# Alert condition / consecutive signal issues

Tags: pine-script

quick question. I've been fiddling around with pinescript for a bit and am stuck. This code I've put together works to plot everything how I want but I can't figure out why alertconditions don't work. They either don't show up as an option in the editor or they go off every bar close regardless of the condition. I didn't include the alertconditions I'd fiddled with cuz they are obviously just wrong. I'm wanting to pair an alert condition to the plotting of the arrows (buyConditions & sellCondition) when price crosses the emas. Any suggestions on how to write those or recode the line that prevents consecutive signals? I imagine that's where the error is but that I haven't been able to finda different way to do that. Still learning.
Thanks

```js
//@version=4
study("3x3", overlay=true)
//inputs
src= close
len= 7
lowband= sma(low,10)
highband= sma(high,20)
mom= src-src[28]
paintbar = mom > 0 ? color.lime : mom < 0 ? color.fuchsia: na
buyCondition = crossunder(low,lowband[1])
sellCondition = crossover(high,highband[1])
//plots
plot(lowband, title="Low SMA", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, offset=1)
plot(highband, title="High SMA", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, offset=1)
barcolor(color=paintbar)

//to avoid multiple signals
bs = 0
bs := buyCondition ? 1 : sellCondition ? 2 : nz(bs[1])


plotshape(bs != bs[1], color = bs == 1 ? color.lime : color.red,title="Order Arrow", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your alertconditions to show up in the editor, you must give them a title.
Also see [How to highlight TradingView alert setups with text and shapes?](https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/show-alerts-shapes-text/)

This is your code, with alertconditions:

```
//@version=4
study("3x3", overlay=true)
//inputs
src= close
len= 7
lowband= sma(low,10)
highband= sma(high,20)
mom= src-src[28]
paintbar = mom > 0 ? color.lime : mom < 0 ? color.fuchsia: na
buyCondition = crossunder(low,lowband[1])
sellCondition = crossover(high,highband[1])
//plots
plot(lowband, title="Low SMA", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, offset=1)
plot(highband, title="High SMA", color=color.orange, linewidth=1, offset=1)
barcolor(color=paintbar)

//to avoid multiple signals
var int bs = na
bs := buyCondition ? 1 : sellCondition ? 2 : 0

alertcondition(buyCondition, title="buyCondition Title", message="Buy here")
alertcondition(sellCondition, title="sellCondition Title", message="Sell here")


plotshape(bs != 0, color = bs == 1 ? color.lime : color.red,title="Order Arrow", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar)
```

Comment: Thank you. that solved it. Could have sworn I'd done that in a previous version but I guess not.